# Configure change markers in PhpStorm

Tags: git, version-control, editor, phpstorm

I would like to confirm the PhpStorm change markers not to be be changes since the last commit but all changes in the current local branch.

Otherwise I lose these changes every time I commit (very often) but I'd like to see a working overview of all the changes I'm currently working on in the local branch.

Answer (score -1):

The reference for the git change (git diff) option is the last commit. Commit is the base of engine of Git.

If you change file which not tracking with git your working overview don't changes (just notice that you have a non tracking file)

You can view the ancient change git with the git history function in PHPStorm (very useful!)

You can also view diff with branch, history of branch local or remote etc....
Very many tricks for view diff in PHPStorm